# did cheapfaresnow.com just screw me over?

Tags: tickets, scams

Really bad idea I booked with them without reviewing their services. There was a fairly cheap ticket and I purchased it. It took time to be confirmed or for me to get an email. I asked for live help and the person was very casual 'just wait two hours'. And nothing. Ten hours later, I noticed my card was charged but no ticket. in their page, it says pending. Then I was told to add $69, which I said no. The customer agent ended the chat session instantly. Long story short, I got on the phone and the woman said they have refunded my ticket and it will show up in 7-10 days and my reservation shows as 'Cancelled'. But now I got an email from them:

```
Passenger Type  Passengers  Ticket Price    Taxes & Fees    Total
Adult   1   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
Total Trip Cost:    $300.00 USD
```

I don't know what to make of it. I already contacted the airline and they are taking forever to reply.

There was no further transaction activity and I have emptied the card right away for fear. For those who have experience wit the website (which is Indians and super careless tone-wise), should I cancel my card as well? Is there anyway to get refund or at least know what Cancelled mean to them?

NEVER AGAIN cheapfaresnow.com

Comment: This is not really about travelling. You could have a similar experience with someone selling anything - and the answer of talking to your bank would be the same, even less related to travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Travel

Answer (score 3):

When you are in dispute with a merchant about a card transaction, you need to talk to your bank about it.

Comment: thank you. Finally my bank replied and are asking all sort of questions.